# how to use geocode in listview to show the map

Tags: android, listview, google-geocoder

I have a listview of address in which if I press any row it should show the particular address in map. For that I'm using Geoocder to get the latitude and longitude of that address.

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

      lvEmployees = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvEmployees);


      lvEmployees.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            String address;
            Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            List<Address> address1;


            // If Google Play Services is available


            // Display Selected Row of Listview into EditText widget

            Cursor row = (Cursor) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            try {
                String strAddress=row.getString(0)+" "+row.getString(2);
                System.out.println("strAddress>>>"+strAddress);
                address1 = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);

                Address location = address1.get(0);

                latitude= location.getLatitude();
                longitude=  location.getLongitude();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
            System.out.println(latitude+" "+longitude);
            String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+ latitude + ","+longitude;
            Intent geoIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(geoIntent);
            System.out.println("url>>"+url);

        }

    }
```

The problem is for all addresses I'm getting the same latitude and langitude values.

please provide some solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have only one instance of ur adress so it takes the last value given 
What you need to do is put the declaration adress data in your listview ArraysAdapter class and send it as a parameter when  you need it

Comment: can you please explain with some example code, if possible.